# Missing oils and potions

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am missing a few oils and potions but find myself with Crowns to burn.  Are there any merchants that will sell oil/potion recipes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for the master alchemist on Skellige. His house (cave?) is located near the sacred druid grounds near two big oaks. You do a quest with

> Yennefer

there. Also for him to sell you any ingredients or recipes you need to finish a quest chain involving some fetching things for him.

Here's a map showing his location:
[image: Gremist location]

Source: [Gosu Noob](http://www.gosunoob.com/witcher-3/practicum-in-advanced-alchemy/)

I've played Polish version of the game and his name was "Gremista", so I expect it to be somewhat similiar in English - like "The Gremist" or something like this.